# How to obtain label data for c# application

Tags: c#

I am looking to integrate label printing into my application. Does anybody know where I can obtain the data required to build up my own database of label data, such as label width, height, diameter, vertical pitch, gutters etc? Just like Microsoft Office Word.

I contacted one supplier (Avery) direct and they told me that they do not provide such information. However there are plenty of software applications out there that have this data built into their systems. I have also looked at the Microsoft Access Database that powers Words label printing (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\ACCWIZ\ACWZUSR12.ACCDU). However the data provided does not seem to tally with the label manufacturers data.

Any help on this one would be much appreciated.

UPDATE - Screenshot of Avery Label L7160 record in Access Database
[image]

Screenshot of L7160 label in word

[image]

Comment: Maybe the people who wrote the software went and bought the labels, then figured out the various pieces of data that way?

Comment: I did think that for about 1 second, but there are thousands of different labels by different manufacturers There are probably about 3000 common lables ranging from Avery, Brother, Dymo etc. A lot of them are based on Avery labels but I thought there must be some core standard data available somewhere??

Comment: @Cragly: If you have Access 2007 installed, it's in an access database located at:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\ACCWIZ\ACWZUSR12.ACCDU"

Comment: @0A0D: Thanks but is this somehow different to the one in Office 2010 which I mentioned in my question?

Comment: @Cragly: It may have updated labels but at least you'll have most of them.

Comment: @0A0D: I have updated my question with an image of a record in that database. As I mentioned in my original question the data held in that database for that label does not match the data for that label ie i can work out what the dxLabel and dyLabel fields are representing. I have also included the data from within word for the same label and nothing corresponds. Or am I missing something??

Comment: @Cragly: It looks like it corresponds, but it is in `mm` in the access database and in `cm` in Word.

Comment: @0A0D: Still not convinced for example the dxLabel field has the value 3552. Now if this was converted to cm it would be 355.2 cm which is a very large value for a label property. even it it was somehow representing 2 decimal places it would still me 35.2 cm. I just cant make the numbers work in this database. A simple one to work with is the dxSpace/dySpace. dySpace is 0 which is correct but the dxSpace is 192 which according to Avery the horizontal space between the labels is 2.5 mm.

Comment: http://www.red-bean.com/labelnation/label-dimensions.html, http://www.red-bean.com/labelnation/

Comment: Look at this code.. it has all the dimensions : http://viewvc.red-bean.com/labelnation/trunk/labelnation?revision=193&view=markup

Comment: Thanks again have spent some time going over the Python code. Howerver the sizes are all incorrect (with current label data). The data has also been manually entered and does not use the Microsoft data highlighted. I also tried to convert the Microsoft data from PostScript Points to mm thinking it may be stored in points rather than mm. Yet again nothing adds up. I think I may have to give up on this one as there doesnt seem to be a solution. I hate to let something beat me! Thanks again for all your help its much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the only data I could find was that provided by Microsoft within its Office application. After contacting many suppliers I was informed most of this information was obtained via partnerships between the label companies. As I am a lone developer I was not able to obtain this data I had to obtain what data I could via the internet and physically measure the more popular labels data by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are looking for is usually provided by ISO...so just look at http://www.iso.org/iso/home.htm and u might find something really usefull about a lot of standards in a lot of business.

Comment: Unfortunately i could not find any of this data provided by ISO. Thanks anyway.